# Moving through a NSDictionary getting objects that you do not know the 'Key' for? IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a NSDictionary that I get from a webservice. Each object in this dictionary contains an array. I do not know how many objects there are going to be in the NSDictionary, or what the 'Key' for each object is going to be beforehand. I only know that it will be a Dictionary of arrays.

How can I enumerate through the dictionary reading out the name of the Object and its content into arrays?

All my dealings with Dictionaries so far I could use

```
[anotherDict objectForKey:@"accounts"]
```

because I know the 'Keys; to expect beforehand.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this :

```
NSArray * keys = [dictionnary allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
   NSArray *tmp = [dictionnary objectForKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

NSDictionary has the method: `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` since iOS 4.0. It's very straightforward, it receives a block object to operate on entries in the dictionary.

An example:

```
[anotherDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
   NSArray *arr = obj;
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` class has an instance method `-allKeys` which returns an `NSArray` with `NSStrings` for all the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Way WOuld be to fetch allKeys via the allKeys instance method

```
NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeys];
```

then iterating over dictionary with for each key.

```
for (NSString *k in keys)
{
    id object = [myDictionary objectForKey:k];
}
```

You can also get keys in order as if values were sorted using

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not a pro but i know that you can get all the  keys of an dictionary

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[Your_Dictionary allKeys]);
```

This will give an array of keys in that dictionary.